# Replace single quotes, but not if within double quotes to use JSON.parse()

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, data-extraction

I need a solution to only **exchange pairs of single quotes**, which are **NOT within a pair of double quotes**.

A simplified example (original is > 100 KB):

```
['Element1',"Element's2",{"Element3":"E3"},'Element4']
```

In this example *Element's2* **should not** become *Element"s2*, but *'Element1'* **should** become *"Element1"*.

Background:
I need to extract some website data contained in big Javascript blocks. To get it i need JOSN.parse() which does not accept single quotes (') as quotes.

but i can not simply use `replace(/'/g, '"')`, because the single quote is also used as apostrophe in some texts like: *"that's it"*.

BTW: As @hakre recommenced, **a much more simple solution for my case** was to use `eval()` instead of `JOSN.parse()`. With `eval()` there was no need to exchange the single quotes.

Comment: Far better to fix the source of this erroneous content in the first place.

Comment: The source is EBAY! How should i fix it? What's wrong with my question (-1)?

Comment: Instead of trying to fix this, you might want to find a different parser that can parse this format. YAML might cover this. Or perhaps a parser which accepts the full Javascript syntax, not just JSON.

Comment: thanks deceze, for the advice. i have tried it here: https://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/. It worked with my short example, but unfortunately not with more complex the 150kb which i get out of the ebay page.

Comment: @Lutz - I didn't downvote your question (or answer). Be careful not to make assumptions. Re eBay: So? Tell them to fix it. If it's meant to be JSON, it's broken. I don't care if Douglas Crockford himself is providing it. :-)

Comment: What does Ebay say where the format is specified? Likely there exists an URL, doesn't it? Shouldbe added to the question.

Comment: This is rather trivial (but to enter as markdown): `eval(\`['Element1',"Element's2",{"Element3":"E3"},'Element4']\`);` > `Array ["Element1", "Element's2", Object { Element3: "E3" }, "Element4"]` - looks like the format is javascript.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: it's simply a script part of the ebay.de article page, which is holding all the details of article variants and more data. it's not made for parsing, JSON or what ever. it's for ebay's internal use. (i'm sure they would say: use the API!). Anyhow i wanted to go this way without an api key. and it worked. I use it in tampermonkey as my privat ebay extension to generate a list of all variants, sorted by price. (some (chinese) sellers hide one cheap variant, between 50 more expensive ones, to let the offer look more cheap.)

Comment: @hakre: yes it's javascript. and yes, you are right. eval() solves it, without any change of single quotes. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a second variant, which also cares about escaped quotes like:`[\'Element1\',"Element's2",{"Elements3":"E3"},'Element\'s4']`

but it is a bit slower and the code looks a bit more complicated (so i use the other variant):

```js
function convert(input) {

    var openQuote 
    var close = {symbol:null,level:0,firstPos:null}
    openQuote = close;
    const singleQuote = "'"
    const doubleQuote = '"'
    const replaceBy = '"'
    var pairCount = 0
    var data = Array.from(input)

    function replacePair(data, newChar, firstPos, secondPos) {
        data[firstPos] =  newChar;
        data[secondPos] =  newChar;
        pairCount++
    }

    function checkEscaped (data, pos, level = 0) {
        if (pos <= 0) return level
        if (data[pos-1] ==  "\\")  { return checkEscaped(data,pos-1,level+1) }
        return level
    }

    function checkQuotes(data,pos){

        if (data[pos] == singleQuote) {
        let level = checkEscaped(data, pos)

          if (openQuote.symbol == null) {openQuote = {symbol: singleQuote, level: level, firstPos: pos}; return}
          if (openQuote.symbol == singleQuote && openQuote.level == level) {replacePair(data,replaceBy,openQuote.firstPos,pos); openQuote = close; return;}
          return
        }

        if (data[pos] == doubleQuote) {
        let level = checkEscaped(data, pos)

          if (openQuote.symbol == null) {openQuote = {symbol: doubleQuote, level: level, firstPos: pos}; return}
          if (openQuote.symbol == doubleQuote && openQuote.level == level) {openQuote = close; return;}
        }
    }

    for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      checkQuotes(data,i)
    }

    var result = data.join("");
    console.log(pairCount , "Pairs of Single Quotes exchanged")
    return result
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var dataIn = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var output = document.getElementById('output').value = convert(dataIn)
});
```

```html
<html><body>
<button id="start">start</button><BR>

Input:<br><textarea id="input" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="100" spellcheck="false">
[\'Element1\',"Element's2",{"Elements3":"E3"},'Element\'s4']
</textarea><BR>

Output:<br><textarea id="output" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="100" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
 
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have build this script to solve my problem. Even if is downvoted, this one works for my case and is a bit more fast.

```js
function convert(input) {

    const singleQuote = "'"
    const doubleQuote = '"'
    const replaceBy = '"'
    var firstSingleQuote = null
    var firstDoubleQuote = null
    var pairCount = 0
    var data = Array.from(input)

    function replacePair(data, newChar, firstPos, secondPos) {
        data[firstPos] =  newChar;
        data[secondPos] =  newChar;
        pairCount++
    }

    function checkQuotes(data,pos){
        if (data[pos] == singleQuote) {
          if (firstSingleQuote == null && firstDoubleQuote == null) { firstSingleQuote = pos; return; }
          if (firstSingleQuote != null && firstDoubleQuote == null) { replacePair(data,replaceBy,firstSingleQuote,pos); firstSingleQuote = null; return; }
          if (firstSingleQuote == null && firstDoubleQuote != null) { return; }
          if (firstSingleQuote != null && firstDoubleQuote != null) { return; }
        }

        if (data[pos] == doubleQuote) {
          if (firstDoubleQuote == null && firstSingleQuote == null) { firstDoubleQuote = pos; return; }
          if (firstDoubleQuote != null && firstSingleQuote == null) { firstDoubleQuote = null; return; }  // todo: replace doubleQuote if wanted!!
          if (firstDoubleQuote == null && firstSingleQuote != null) { return; }
          if (firstDoubleQuote != null && firstSingleQuote != null) { return; }
        }
    }

    for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
      checkQuotes(data,i)
    }

    var result = data.join("");
    console.log(pairCount , "Pairs of Single Quotes exchanged")
    return result
}

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', () => {
    var dataIn = document.getElementById('input').value;
    var output = document.getElementById('output').value = convert(dataIn)
});
```

```html
<html><body>
<button id="start">start</button><BR>

Input:<br><textarea id="input" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="100" spellcheck="false">
['Element1',"Element's2",{"Element3":"E3"},'Element4']
</textarea><BR>

Output:<br><textarea id="output" name="w3review" rows="2" cols="100" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
 
</body></html>
```

Comment: `'Elemen\'t1'` becomes `"Elemen\"t1"`, which is incorrect. That's not the same string. It should be `"Elemen\'t1"` (or `"Elemen't1"`).

Comment: good point. yes, i know, but this was not part of my problem. to get a more general solution, which cares also about escaped quotes, it needs to do more. in my case this was simply not needed. feel free to extend my solution to care about this. :)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: i added a second answer, which solves the case of escaped quotes like `'Elemen\'t1'` , `'Elemen\\\'t1'` or `\'Elemen't1\'`